# Ubuntu 14.04 - Modify OpenVPN files manually

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, python3

I am using a `VPN` (Private Tunnel) to download stuff / play games at dorms (ports are blocked, VPN allows me to bypass that). I also am trying to create a `script in python` that allows me to create new VPN connection fast. I was wondering if there was a way to somehow manually modify files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, or create new ones, using some sort of text editor or something.

I want to try to create a script that gives directions to `certificates, keys`, sets up `gateway`, and sets up options like `use TCP`, `use port 443`, etc; so that I don't have to do it through `Network Manager`. But I am not able to open or modify those files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Is there any way to do it?
How I imagine it:

I would open them in text editor like `gedit` or something, and using python I would replace some lines each time I get new `keys` and `certificates` from the `VPN provider`.